# Access values from SparseTensorValue

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am parsing a tfrecord file. I get some coordinates in a SparceTensorValue. This is what i get from a print:

```
>> print("coords: ", coords)

>> coords:  SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]]), values=array([0.19      , 0.43666667, 0.555     , 0.7416667 , 0.90166664],
      dtype=float32), shape=array([5]))
```

How do I access the values in a neat way?

What I want is a numpy array:

```
[0.19, 0.44, 0.55, 0.74, 0.90]
```

Comment: Can you share the full program..?

Answer (score 0):

This was actually way easier than I thought. Turns out all I had to do was the following:

```
>> print("coords: ",coords.values)
>> coords:  [0.19       0.43666667 0.555      0.7416667  0.90166664]
```